# Chef - execute vs bash resource

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, recipe

I used both the `execute` resource or the `bash` resource.

Both achieve the same result:

```
bash 'Execute my script' do 
  user 'root'
  cwd  '/mydir'
  code <<-EOH
    ./myscript.sh
  EOH
end

execute 'Execute my script' do 
  user    'root'
  cwd     '/mydir'
  command './myscript.sh'
end
```

The only difference I see is that `bash` actually creates a shell script (named `/tmp/chef-script#{date}{#id}`) where `code` is written.

What is the best practice to execute a shell script with Chef between `execute` or `bash` resource ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a single script, use an `execute`. The `bash` resource is for including the script contents inline in the recipe code.

Answer (score -1):

In bash & execute block we need to write code to catch the error as if you add more than one command & the chef takes the status of the last command.
To make it more clear - when the Bash/execute  block has only one command chef catches the issue ,if the next command is successful then it takes the last command status.

```
bash 'Execute my script' do 
  user 'root'
  cwd  '/mydir'
  code <<-EOH
    ./myscript.sh
    ls srini ##This will fail
    ls  ## this will be successful
  EOH
end

execute 'Execute my script' do 
  user    'root'
  cwd     '/mydir'
  command './myscript.sh'
  command 'ls srini' #will fail
  command 'ls' # will be successful
end
```

Comment: According to the manual (https://docs.chef.io/resources/execute), each `execute` resource should include only one `command` property.